# Deploying Python Function Application with DevOps is moving files but not actually deploying application

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This is a repost of this question, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462841/deploying-python-function-application-with-devops
adding to SO to get more views.

A Python Azure Function (Model V2) was created using VS Code and following the Microsoft article linked below, with the default code for the Function Application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators

A Build Pipeline and a Release Pipeline were set up in Azure DevOps, using the article linked below (which is a few years old). The Tasks in the Release pipeline are not the same as the article, but everything else seemed to flow well.

https://medium.com/globant/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-python-azure-function-using-azure-devops-ci-cd-2aa8f8675716

From the currently available tasks, the “Azure Function Deploy”-task  seemed the best and only fit. The screenshot below shows the Tasks available.

[image]

When the Release Pipeline is run, it runs successfully. All of the files were moved to the Function Application service according to the screenshot below.  It ran multiple times with edits to comments in the default “function_app.py” file and new files added to ensure the build pipeline + deployment pipeline were moving the documents.

[image]

However, there is no actual Function running and available to interact with.  (See screenshot below).  Any idea on what modification is needed in the Deployment pipeline to make this work?

[image]

EDIT:

The instructions in the response from @wade-zhou-msft were attempted by my colleague, and here was her response:

"Hello @Wade Zhou - thank you for posting this answer.  I did confirm that the code works when deployed directly from VS Code.  So this is not a function code problem.  I tried to recreate your yaml code using the pipeline builder, as I am a beginner and I am not familiar with yaml files.  I did not get it to run successfully.  Can you provide some insight on how is the repo associated with the DevOps Pipeline you used for testing and in your response?  Currently, my repo looks like the screenshot below. Perhaps I have to create an artifact that only looks at the Function App code.

[image]

Note that I cloned the repo into my local machine before creating my Azure Function workspace.  The workspace for VS Code was created within the repo, and then merged into master branch of the repo.

I tried the copy activity, I got it to work, but still having issues with the artifact step picking up the files from the sub directory"

Comment: Hi @Mike, may i know if there's any update? You can follow the reply below to confirm the app and deployment. Let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and I created the function with the v1 model instead the v2, and it worked for me.

I couldn't do it with v2 model... it was a strong lost battle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same doc to create the python function app, and deploy it via DevOps pipeline it works fine on my side.
[image]

Please follow below steps for a check:

1. It appears you have two .py files in your app. After you create the function app on VS code, you can create a test function app on azure, and deploy it from VS code directly, make sure the function app is working fine, that will validate the you have correct code.  Detail steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators#deploy-the-project-to-azure) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators#run-the-function-in-azure). If it's not working, please follow the doc to recreate the function app.

[image]

[image]

2. Once you confirm the test function app is working, you can push your code to DevOps repo. Create the target function app service on azure. The deployment steps are mentioned in doc [Continuous delivery with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=python%2Cyaml&pivots=v2). Follow the doc, to create the yaml pipeline(recommended) which works same with classic UI editor pipeline. You can also find the classic UI task guide in the doc.

I used python 3.11 when creating the function app, hence i specify 3.11 on pipeline. My yaml for your reference. You can also check the artifact zip file generated in pipeline to confirm the content deployed.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  # Azure service connection established during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: YourAzureResourceServiceConnection
  appName: functionappname

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: "Setting Python version to yours"
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.11'
    addToPath: true
    architecture: 'x64'
- bash: |
    if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
    then
        dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
    fi
    pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop'

- task: AzureFunctionApp@2 # Add this at the end of your file
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appType: functionAppLinux # default is functionApp
    appName: $(appName)
    package: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip
    deploymentMethod: 'auto' # 'auto' | 'zipDeploy' | 'runFromPackage'. Required. Deployment method. Default: auto.
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @wadezhou-MSFT - I am replying on behalf of my colleague, who originally brought this question to me. Since it requires an image, I will reply with an edit the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As per the new screenshot, your code is under folder `TesterFunctionPython`,  you can remove the folder and directly put the code in the repo. Otherwise you need to specify the correct path for each yaml steps when path is used.

Answer (score 0):

I built a pipeline with the classic builder, my repo had the the Azure Function app workspace as a folder and the Read Me document (like @Mike showed in his posted question), and modified the Archive zip building step. The release pipeline finally deployed to the Azure Function Service correctly after including only the files pertaining to the function within the artifact.

I modified the "Root folder or file to archive" to point to the Function folder so it only picked up the Function App files when creating the artifact.
[screenshot of the Archive task in the Pipeline set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb5HW.png)